# Cómo quitar el tag de la slug en WordPress sin plugins

Tags: wordpress, slug

Tengo un problema con la url en la que aparece la eqtiqueta ‘tag’. Quiero quitarla y no veo la forma. Lo que quiero hacer es por ejemplo

mipagina.com/tag/restaurante convertirlo en mipagina.com/restaurante

He podido hacerlo con el category mediante Rank Math pero no lo puedo hacer para tag. También he probado a cambiarlo en los permalinks y añadiendo código en el functions.php

```
function remove_tag( $string, $type )
{
if($type != ‘single’ && $type == ‘post_tag’ && (strpos( $string, ‘tag’ ) !== false))
{
$url_without_tag = str_replace( «/tag/», «/», $string );
return trailingslashit( $url_without_tag );
}
}

return $string;
}

add_filter( ‘user_trailingslashit’, ‘remove_tag’, 100, 2);
```

Pero tampoco funciona. No entiendo que le pasa aunque si he podido detectar que $type == ‘post_tag’ lo evalua como false, por tanto no entra.

Si me pueden ayudar estaré muy agradecida.

Gracias por su tiempo